# Get out of brackets and parenthesis with Tab

Tags: sublimetext, visual-studio-code, brackets

**The problem is** you have to use arrows or Macros to jump out of parenthesis, square brackets, curly brackets, single quotes and double-quotes.

Comment: You may want to take the answer out of the question and keep them separate

Comment: I did that but Vijay suggested to append them. I'll separate them again 

Answer (score 0):

**The easy solution I found** to this problem :

**[VSCode]** there's an extension called **TabOut**, install it (done).

**[SublimeText3]** we have to make some changes to Key Bindings
Preferences>Key Bindings
copy and paste the snippet below to the right side pane, save and close this window.
(tested and working ✌)

```
[
    { "keys": ["("], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "($1)$0"}, "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
    ]
},


{ "keys": ["{"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{$1}$0"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },

{ "keys": ["["], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "[$1]$0"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|;|\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$1\"$0"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "'$1'$0"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "['a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
]
```